# Cannot send data to mysql server from android

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-asynctask

first of all, before write this post I tried to find a solution by myself searching info everywhere, but I've found nothing that helps me.

Well, I'm developping an Android application that receives data from a server and also sends data to that server. Receiving data it's ok, but when I try to send could occur:

- The first time data is sent OK, but the second time it freezes in httpResponse.
- Since I start my app, it can't send anything. It freezes when click "send".

I debbug but I can't find anything. Now it shows "Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at..." and sometimes log shows "Skipped xxx frames". I launch an AsyncTask.

I've tried to put a timeout, it finishes but without making changes in server. I put mysqli_close() or entity.consume(), but nothing changes.

I'll appreciate any kind of help. Thank you.

Here's my code (I'll sum up a bit):

php class

```
$con = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())  
 {  
      echo "Imposible conectarse a la base de datos: " . mysqli_connect_error();  
 }
 else{
    $response = array();

    // Recogemos los detalles del usuario
    $xxxx = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['xxxx']);
    $xxxx = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['xxxx']);

    // Insertamos la fila
    $result = $con->query("INSERT INTO tareas(xxxx, xxxx) VALUES(xxxx, xxxx)");

    if ($result) {
        ...
```

Android classes

In my main class I call AsyncTask class

```
public void crearInforme(){

        CrearNuevoInforme cni = new CrearNuevoInforme(informe);
        cni.execute();
...
```

AsyncTask class

```
...
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("xxxx", xxxx));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("xxxx", xxxx));

    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_Connect, "POST", params);
...
```

And then jsonParser

```
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method.equals("POST")){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                HttpEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "utf-8");
                httpPost.setEntity(entity);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost); <---Here's
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

Comment: Note: `method == "POST"` Don't compare String values using `==`. Use `equals()`

Comment: I'm testing with doing AsyncTaks parallel. After some time, the row is inserted in mysql, but it's too slow. Could it be any property of the database? it's innoDB. Thank you